# How to simulate drag and drop feature using protractor for e2e?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop, protractor, end-to-end

Hi the HTML code for drag used is:

```
  <div class="btn-event"
   dnd-type="'newEvent'" dnd-draggable="event"
   dnd-effect-allowed="copy" dnd-copied="">
  <div class="icon">
  <i class='demo'></i>
  </div>
  <span class="label" title="Object Name">
  {{O.name}}
  </span>
  </div>
```

The code for drop is:

```
  <div class="row slot-body"
  dnd-list="sequenceSlot.events"
  dnd-allowed-types="['newEvent']"
  dnd-drop="Drop(event, index, item, external, type, dropped item)"
  dnd-dragover="Drop.validate(event, index, type)">
```

Are we supposed to search by dragabble ? Or by css ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `dragAndDrop()` action method, example:

```
browser.actions().dragAndDrop(
    element(by.css("div[dnd-draggable]")),
    element(by.css("div[dnd-dragover]"))
).perform();
```

Comment: It is a list right. So how to control which element of the list is to be dragged ?